# Function context is different to function assigned as variable

Tags: javascript, dom, this

I see several questions about callbacks: obviously, there is no callback involved here, and I'm struggling to see the relevance of any of the previous answers. I don't doubt that there is some relevance, just that none of the previous answers explain or demonstrate that relevance.

To be clear: I don't know how renaming a function by using a procedural variable changes context. That would be obvious if I was implementing a callback, but I'm not: I've not moved to the call to a different object by using a callback, and I don't know what the new context is, or how or why it changed.

I've got a function:

```
export default class Popup {
  shower(label, value, valueList, saveEvent) {
    let classInstance = this;
    let domObjects = [ classInstance.dom.text(label, "p") ];
  }
}
```

Which is called like this:

```
export default class Controller {
  constructor(model, view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;
  }

function fred(void){
    fn=this.view.popup.shower;
    fn(label, stat.value, lst, myOtherfn);
```

}

..But that doesn't work. If fails because, when called that way, there is something undefined about

```
classInstance.dom.text(label, "p")
```

(when called from the exact same place as a normal call, it works correctly)

```
function fred(void){
    this.view.popup.shower(label, stat.value, lst, myOtherfn); 
}
```

I don't know enough about javascript even to be dangerous. What does **dom.text("mytext"
, "p")** mean?  Apparently I get a different **this.dom** from the two call methods? And how can I use a variable procedure in a way that doesn't mess with context?

Comment: `this` is called the "context", not "scope"

Comment: @Bergi thanks. At least learned one thing :) I've corrected the quesion. However, it looks like I won't be able to ask the question anyway.